# Support https searches in opensearch.xml

Tags: feature-request, search, ssl

I was trying to add search providers to Microsoft Edge. I know StackOverflow supports OpenSearch so I tried to add it. However, I get an error message saying the search template is not using a secure connection. I tried the same procedure while visiting https://www.stackoverflow.com/ but the result is the same.

Is it possible to at least change the url in the opensearch.xml file to use https?

The [opensearch.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/opensearch.xml) file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<OpenSearchDescription xmlns="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/" xmlns:moz="http://www.mozilla.org/2006/browser/search/">
  <ShortName>Stack Overflow</ShortName>
  <Description>Search Stack Overflow: Q&amp;A for professional and enthusiast programmers</Description>
  <InputEncoding>UTF-8</InputEncoding>
  <Image width="16" height="16" type="image/x-icon">//sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico</Image>
  <Url type="text/html" method="get" template="https://stackoverflow.com/search?q={searchTerms}"></Url>
</OpenSearchDescription>
```

Requirements for adding a search provider to Edge ([source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt203634(v=vs.85).aspx)):

> **Important** For user security and privacy, Microsoft Edge requires that
>   all searches be conducted over SSL. Therefore, the following pages and
>   URLs must be https URLs:
>
> - The site that contains the reference to the description document
> - The URL to the description document itself
> - The search query template

Instructions for adding a search provider to Edge ([source](http://www.bing.com/search?q=How%20do%20i%20change%20the%20default%20search%20engine%20in%20microsoft%20edge&filters=guid:%22a00d6f28-1eb7-455d-ab08-0e5072341b54%22%20lang:%22en-us%22&form=S00028)):

1. Go to the search engine’s website.
2. Select More actions (...) > Settings > View advanced settings.  In
   the list under Search in the address bar with,  choose Add new.
3. Select the website and then select Add. Note: Only search providers
   that support the OpenSearch standard will appear in this list. If
   they don’t support it yet, here's how they can. Keep checking back
   to see who's been added to the list.
4. To set this site as your default search provider, go back to the
   list under Search the address bar with and choose it.

Comment: SE's enthusiasm for https considerably cooled since the Heartbleed disaster.   Last I heard it is on indefinite hold.  You are probably better off posting this question at meta.stackexchange.com

Comment: @HansPassant It hasn't cooled, the devs are just down to the harder issues (you'll notice a lot of work going on around auth / login / cookie changes / etc) (that's not to promise that it's near or anything, but it's still a thing AFAIK)

Comment: Dropping the `www` from the URL solves the issue of the opensearch.xml file coming back over HTTP. Search, however, is still going to come back with mixed content warnings. Is there any way to 'allow' that?